# Get instance underneath another

Tags: object, instance, game-maker

I'm trying to create a blood effect in my game, to achieve this I need to test whether or not the blood particle hit another instance from an array. I already have the array set up and a way to test if the object is in the array but when i do this:

```
platform = instance_position(x, y, all);
```

It will target the blood particle itself while I want the instance underneath. Is there any way of ignoring the blood particle and instead looking at the instance underneath it? I can't change the depth because I do want it to be in the front.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for collision with one particular object or instance, you can use the object name or instance ID in place of the **all** keyword. Example:

```
var ins = instance_position(x, y, objWall);
```

If any instances of *objWall* are detected, the ID of the first of those instances will be returned. If you use an instance ID instead, only that single instance will be checked for.

If you need to check for multiple different instances, you could loop through the array, performing one check per instance ID and stopping the loop if one of them is found.

If you need to check for multiple object types, you could assign a Parent to those objects and then do a check for the parent. Example: Make four objects, *objBallParent, objFootball, objBouncyBall, objCannonBall*. In the Object Properties of each ball, set objBallParent as the Parent object.

```
if ( instance_exists(objBallParent ) {
    // Do something
}

var closest = instance_nearest(x, y, objBallParent);
```

The code above only checks for the parent object, but the functions will be satisfied by any instances of the child objects as well. In this case, if there is an instance of *objFootball* in the room, that will count as an instance of *objBallParent* existing, and it can also be returned by the *instance_nearest* function.

When checking for collisions with objBallParent, any of the three child objects would be accepted by the check.